# Calling a method in another class causes NullPointerException

Tags: java

I am new to Java so please bear with me. I am using Java and Selenium to test a web application.

Basically, what I am trying to do is read in data from a cvs file in Class Main and then once I have the data, calling the login method in another class passing through the username and password variables read from the cvs file.

Maybe I am calling the function incorrectly, I am not sure but the line I get the NPE on is

```
driver.findElement(By.name("j_username")).clear();
```

in the Login function in the LiveProcess Class. If I move the Login method into the Main class I do not have any problems. I would appreciate any help you can give me - thanks in advance!

Main Class

```
public void ReadTestData() throws Exception
{
//Open CVS File and extract the contents
try {
CsvReader testData = new CsvReader("C:\\Selenium\\TestData.csv");   
testData.readHeaders();
while (testData.readRecord())
{
String testType = testData.get("TestType");
String testName = testData.get("TestName");
String testDescription = testData.get("Description");
String userName = testData.get("UserName");
String password = testData.get("Password");
String firstName = testData.get("FirstName");
String lastName = testData.get("LastName");
int testTypeInt = Integer.parseInt(testType);
RunTests();
}   
testData.close();

} 
catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
{
e.printStackTrace();
} 
catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}

public void RunTests() throws Exception
{
switch(testTypeInt)
{
case 1:
LiveProcessTests method = new LiveProcessTests();
method.Login(userName, password);
break;

default:
break;
}
}
```

LiveProcess Class

```
public void Login(String uName, String pWord) throws Exception 
{
System.out.println("USER NAME: " + uName);
System.out.println("USER NAME: " + pWord);

driver.findElement(By.name("j_username")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.name("j_username")).click();
driver.findElement(By.name("j_username")).sendKeys(uName);

}
```

Actual Error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.testscripts.LiveProcessTests.Login(LiveProcessTests.java:31)
at com.testscripts.Main.RunTests(Main.java:97)
at com.testscripts.Main.ReadTestData(Main.java:75)
at com.testscripts.Main.InitializeTests(Main.java:44)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Comment: You could just debug the application to see what exactly is null in that line, but it might be `driver`. Do you initialize `driver` in the `LiveProcess` class?

Comment: First, where do you declare your `driver` variable ? Secondly, how can your RunTests method work ? The testTypeInt is declared in another method. You should have an exception there... You should pass variables to your RunTests method, at least `RunTests(testTypeInt,userName,password)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most likely `driver.findElement(By.name("j_username"))` is null which means it is unable to find the element you are searching.

Make sure the name is correct and that the element exist. Also You have to initialise the driver but it is not seen in your code

Example:

```
if (driver.findElement(By.name("j_username")) != null ) {
    driver.findElement(By.name("j_username")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.name("j_username")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.name("j_username")).sendKeys(uName);
}
```

**UPDATE:**

You should initialize your driver. Something like:

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Comment: Exactly - searching by name means that it should find element which would look like this: `<input type="text" name="j_username">`  Dont you want to search by ID?

Comment: @Adel

Thanks for your quick comments. Unfortunately even if I use your code I still get NPE on that line: if (driver.findElement(By.name("j_username")) != null ). If I use this line outside of this function it finds the field no problem

Comment: @user1145782 then driver is null :) Solved!

Comment: @user1145782 please show us the code where you initialize driver

Comment: @Adel Boutros - Eh I don't think I initialize the driver - this is the first time I use that statement. I am sorry I am only learning this

Comment: @Pavel Janick, the id is not available

Comment: @Adel Boutros, this is where I declare driver:

    private WebDriver driver;

Comment: @user1145782 you are declaring but you are not initializing. Check my updated answer

Comment: @Adel Boutros thanks but I get error now saying I cannot instantiate the type WebDriver. Sorry in my Main class I do initialize it:


driver = new FirefoxDriver();

Comment: @user1145782 then initialize it the same way `driver = new FirefoxDriver();` also

Comment: @Adel Boutros, Thanks I see my issue now, If I initlize it same way I lose the state of it so driver = new FirefoxDriver(); brings up a firebox browser. I don't want that to happen every time I call methods in different classes. So I declare driver in my main class but can I use it in my LiveProcess class without declaring it again?

Comment: @user1145782 Yes you simply pass it as a function parameter and use it wherever you need it. OR add it a class attirubute, setting it at the constructor and using it wherever you need

Comment: @Adel Boutros - brilliant that worked thank you so much and sorry to take up so much of your time!